# AWS HTTP API - same request but different response in Python Requests vs Dart HTTP

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dart, python-requests, http-post

I am trying to use AWS DynamoDB in a Flutter app, and given the lack of an official AWS SDK for Dart I am forced to use the low level HTTP REST API.

The method for signing an AWS HTTP request is quite tedious, but using an [AWS supplied sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-post) as a guide, I was able to convert the Python to Dart pretty much line-for-line relatively easily. The end result was both sets of code producing the same auth signatures.

My issue came when I actually went to sent the request. The Python works as expected but sending a POST with Dart's HTTP package gives the error

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

I'll spare you the actual code for generating the auth signature, as the issue can be replicated simply by sending the same request hard-coded. See the Python and Dart code below.

Note: A valid response will return

> Signature expired: 20190307T214900Z is now earlier than
>   20190307T215809Z (20190307T221309Z - 15 min.)

as the request signature uses current date and is only valid for 15 mins.

*****PYTHON CODE*****

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
           'X-Amz-Date':'20190307T214900Z',
           'X-Amz-Target':'DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem',
           'Authorization':'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJFZWA7QQAQT474EQ/20190307/ap-southeast-2/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=297c5a03c59db6da45bfe2fda6017f89a0a1b2ab6da2bb6e0d838ca40be84320'}

endpoint = 'https://dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/'
request_parameters =  '{"TableName": "player-exports","Key": {"exportId": {"S": "HG1T"}}}'

r = requests.post(endpoint, data=request_parameters, headers=headers)

print('Response status: %d\n' % r.status_code)
print('Response body: %s\n' % r.text)
```

*****DART CODE*****

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {

  var headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
           'X-Amz-Date':'20190307T214900Z',
           'X-Amz-Target':'DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem',
           'Authorization':'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJFZWA7QQAQT474EQ/20190307/ap-southeast-2/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=297c5a03c59db6da45bfe2fda6017f89a0a1b2ab6da2bb6e0d838ca40be84320'};

  var endpoint = 'https://dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/';
  var request_parameters =  '{"TableName": "player-exports","Key": {"exportId": {"S": "HG1T"}}}';

  http.post(endpoint, body: request_parameters, headers: headers).then((response) {
    print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("Response body: ${response.body}");
  });
}
```

The endpoint, headers and body are literally copy and pasted between the two sets of code.

Is there some nuance to how Dart HTTP works that I am missing here? Is there some map/string/json conversion of the headers or request_paramaters happening?

One thing I did note is that in the AWS provided example it states

> For DynamoDB, the request can include any headers, but MUST include
>   "host", "x-amz-date", "x-amz-target", "content-type", and
>   "Authorization". Except for the authorization header, the headers must
>   be included in the canonical_headers and signed_headers values, as
>   noted earlier. Order here is not significant. Python note: The 'host'
>   header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.

But

a) When I add 'Host':'dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com' to the headers in the Dart code I get the same result

and

b) If I look at r.request.headers after the Python requests returns, I can see that it has added a few new headers (Content-Length etc) automatically, but "Host" isn't one of them.

Any ideas why the seemingly same HTTP request works for Python Requests but not Dart HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is resolved now. My issue was in part a massive user-error. I was using a new IDE and when I generated the hardcoded example I provided I was actually still executing the previous file. Stupid, stupid, stupid.

But...

I was able to sort out the actual issue that caused me raise the question in the first place. I found that if you set the content type to "application/json" in the headers, the dart HTTP package automatically appends "; charset=utf-8". Because this value is part of the auth signature, when AWS encodes the values from the header to compare to the user-generated signature, they don't match.

The fix is simply to ensure that when you are setting the header content-type, make sure that you manually set it to "application/json; charset=utf-8" and not "application/json".

Found a bit more discussion about this "bug" after the fact [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/184).